# Match only day and month and show records regardless of year in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I only want to fetch the records that were created any year of a given date regardless of the year in Laravel 9. I tried the query below.

```
Posts::query()->where([DAYOFMONTH(created_at)=>date('d', strtotime($dated)), MONTH(created_at)=>date('m', strtotime($dated))])->paginate(10);
```

How can I match only day and month and fetch the records? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are bunch of built in functions for building a query that work with dates and times:

whereDate
whereMonth
whereDay
whereYear
whereTime

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->whereMonth('created_at', '10')->whereDay('created_at', '10')->paginate(15)->get();
```

[read more here](https://webdevetc.com/programming-tricks/laravel/laravel-eloquent/how-to-select-all-rows-for-a-certain-month-or-day-year-or-time-using-eloquent/)